# Does Cucumber support meta-features?

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber

Say I have a set of related features X, Y, and Z.  Each has a detailed list of scenarios that I've fleshed out.

Is there a way to use Cucumber to assert that all three features have been implemented?

Something like:

```
Scenario Outline: All gamma features are ready
  Given feature <f> is part of the gamma release
  When I try to use feature <f>
  Then feature <f> should just work

  Scenarios:
    | f |
    | X |
    | Y |
    | Z |

Then /feature (\S*) should just work/ do |f|
   `cucumber -t@#{f}`  # except less repetitive and more awesome
end
```

I know I could just create a gamma tag and run against that, but I want to document somehow that the totality of the gamma release is ready.  Perhaps this doesn't make sense, but it's not quite clear in my head either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're thinking of it in reverse?

Maybe what you need is to tag everything that's in development for future releases instead.  Then you run:

```
cucumber -t~@delta,~@epsilon
```

to eliminate the future delta and epsilon release features and run alpha, beta and gamma features.

It seems like that would be easier to implement going forward since you would get full regression of the "untagged" alpha, beta and gamma features.

Another option is to simply tag stuff that's in development and remove those tags when features are ready.

```
cucumber -t ~@in_dev
```